# Child Theme Based on Toolbox Not Found

Tags: multisite, child-theme

I am trying to make a child theme of the [toolbox](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/toolbox/) theme and use it in my multisite WP 3.2 install.

I created a folder called `wp-content/themes/charlie-repair-toolkit/` then I created `style.css` in the folder with the following information (some of which is copied from the original theme):

```
/*
Theme Name: Charlie's Repair
Theme URI: http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/toolbox/
Author: Mike Wills
Author URI: http://mikewills.me
Theme: toolbox
Description: Based on the Toolbox theme from Automatic. This site is for Charlie's Repair
Version: 0.1
License: GNU General Public License
License URI: license.txt
Tags: custom-menu, sticky-post, microformats, rtl-language-support, translation-ready

This theme, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.
Use it to make something cool, have fun, and share what you've learned with others.
*/

@import url("../toolbox/style.css");
```

The theme is not shown in the Network Admin or the site's dashboard. Any thoughts as to what I am not doing right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the Template Name for the parent theme. It should look like this:

```
/*
Theme Name: Charlie's Repair
Theme URI: http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/toolbox/
Author: Mike Wills
Author URI: http://mikewills.me
Template: toolbox
Description: Based on the Toolbox theme from Automatic. This site is for Charlie's Repair
Version: 0.1
License: GNU General Public License
License URI: license.txt
Tags: custom-menu, sticky-post, microformats, rtl-language-support, translation-ready

This theme, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.
Use it to make something cool, have fun, and share what you've learned with others.
*/

@import url("../toolbox/style.css");
```

Where you have "Theme: toolbox" it needs to be "Template: toolbox"

Comment: Thanks... I must have missed that somewhere. I could have sworn that the documentation I seen said to use `Theme:`

Comment: You're welcome, it's usually the little details :)

Answer (score 1):

Doing this quickly via mObile phone. I think you need to change 'Theme: toolbox' to 'Template: toolbox'

That's my standard for Thematic child themes.